# How can i add href to this?

Tags: php

This is the code system. takes the order number from customers input and show on admin dashboard.

```
  {:IF}</div>
     IF(!empty("{ORDERS.phone_number}")){
     <div><i class="icon-feather-phone"></i> {ORDERS.phone_number} </div>
```

i want to add "href " code in to this so users can call customers without copying number and paste it.

Answer (score 1):

```
  {:IF}</div>
     IF(!empty("{ORDERS.phone_number}")){
     <a href="tel:{ORDERS.phone_number}"><div><i class="icon-feather-phone"></i>{ORDERS.phone_number}</div></a>
```